# how to use multiline edit textbox to get user-defined matrix data from users in matlab gui

Tags: matlab-guide

I have written a code in MATLAB and it has worked. I started developing GUI for the code. However, I want to collect matrix data from user using multiline edit textbox, with new row distinguished with new line. For example, n×3 matrix: 
3 3 2 
4 4 3 
. . . 
n1 n2 n3

Comment: I didn't get what you really want. Do you want to check and format the user input to the text box? then use keypress event. i.e. use comma as number separator and after each third comma, move the cursor to new line and in the end read the textbox string using sscanf or textscan. If you are sure that user enters the numbers correctly as you wished, then use sscanf or textscan to convert the chars to matrix.

Comment: I'm not formatting user input.Rather I want to use textbox to collect user input.I want to build an app for performing mathematical matrix operations (transpose, inverse, etc). I added edit textbox control to my GUI.When a user of my application types values in the textbox the normal way a matrix is typed in matlab( values separated by space on a line as elements of first row of matrix, new line as new row)in the textbox, and presses a button,eg Determinant button, the result will be displayed in static textbox. My question is: would MATLAB recognize the user input as numeric matrix correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you assume user of your application enters numbers in correct format, then you can use str2num function.

For example, use following code in your button callback:

```
a = get(handles.yourtextboxtag, ‘string’);
b = str2num(a);
```